# SqLite and Classic ASP with JScript

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic, javascript

SqLite is widely pitched as zero install, however I am having problems understanding how I can write data from an asp web form to an sqlite database without installing a dll.

Am wondering if you could point me to some reference as to how to configure sqlite on an ASP server so I can connect to an sqlite database.

In addition is there a way to avoid any notion of installing a dll to manage connecting. Is there another way to connect to an sqlite db without needing to get users to install a dll.

If a dll needs to be installed why do you suppose it is alway talked about as a no install database.

Would appreciate any insight

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlite is zero-**configuration**. Not zero-installation (whatever you think that should mean). on the sqlite homepage you can find many ways to bind from [different languages](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers)

I have had OK results with the cherry city driver, and the ODBC driver at http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ is also good for classic asp integration.

The users don't need to install the DLL, the serever urnning your ASP pages will however need to have it installed